# Facebook OAuth Hanging after successful Login

Tags: c#, facebook, oauth, xamarin, facebook-c#-sdk

I am building some Login with Facebook functionality into my existing app, to use AWS Cogneto. I have based my work on [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/blob/master/XamarinSamples/DynamoDB/) sample, which works. However, My app has a Facebook Login button, which when clicked triggers the Facebook Login Popup. Once I have successfully logged in, the Popup stays and the app hangs without triggering any of the outcome events defined below. The debugger shows that I get to the line `login.LogInWithReadPermissions(...)` without problem, but no further. This is a reference directly to the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/), how can I debug further or fix this problem?

```
private void HandleFacebookLoginClicked()
{
    LoginManager login = new LoginManager();
    var window= UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
    var vc = window.RootViewController;
    while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
    {
        vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
    }
    login.LogInWithReadPermissions(readPermissions.ToArray(), vc, delegate(LoginManagerLoginResult result, NSError error)
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                App.OnFacebookAuthFailed();
            }
            else if (result.IsCancelled)
            {
                App.OnFacebookAuthFailed();
            }
            else
            {
                var accessToken = result.Token;
                App.OnFacebookAuthSuccess(accessToken.TokenString);
            }
        });
}
```

I have tried going through with the Visual Studio debugger, but I don't seem to get any errors or output messages after the window has launched.

Really Stumping me, any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

## NB

I have filed a bug report with Facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/848009398630879), and am going to try to get some help with this, as I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: can you check if you have setup your info.plist correctly?

Comment: @Karthik I think it is fine. I have done a few tests where it wasn't, but I usually get clear debugger errors.